# Pagination on static front page - WordPress

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have a static front page on my [WP portfolio](http://mtthwbsh.com) and have tried using the codex but can't seem to figure out my loops. Here's what my first query looks like:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=portfolio&posts_per_page=4') ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

Any idea what it would look like to paginate it on a static front page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any plugin you can use this (just a simple example)

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args=array('category_name'=>'portfolio','posts_per_page'=>4,'paged'=>$paged);
query_posts($args);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
/...
endwhile;
posts_nav_link();
wp_reset_query();
endif;
```

Visit [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link) to know more about formating links.

Alternatively you can use plugins like [pagenavi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) (I use this) or [infinite scroll](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/infinite-scroll/screenshots/). There is also a nice tutorial if you manually want to build your [infinite scroll](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-pagination/).

Comment: I like the idea of infinite scroll, but I'll have more than one query on the same page (the page is 4 sections with a smooth scroll navigation), this is why I'm opting for the 'load more' button. I'll give this a shot though, thanks!

Comment: This appears to have worked, now onto trying to make the 'load more' button! Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to add something to this. Your retrieval of the current page seems outdated/overly complicate. According to [the Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/#examples) you can use this: `$paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );` The second parameter is the default value if the variable is not set. Probably easier to read than the ternary operator. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin: [wp page navi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/)

it will add page navigation automatically if you have more posts in this query.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks for the response! I am eventually going to use a "load more posts" button instead of pagination, so I'm not sure this will help me out, but I'll take a look at it.

Comment: +1, it's good suggestion but always try to add a brief description in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After reading through decades old posts on various forums Github Co-Pilot just suggested this and it worked perfectly for generating pagination on the static front page

```
  <?php
  $big = 999999999;
  echo paginate_links(array(
    'base' => str_replace($big, '%#%', esc_url(get_pagenum_link($big))),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max(1, $paged),
    'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text' => __('« Previous', 'textdomain'),
    'next_text' => __('Next »', 'textdomain'),
  ));
  ?>
```